# How do you associate click events of buttons created in code in C# with methods?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I'm building a Windows Phone app and I can't make a dynamically created Button associate with its event handler.

The code I'm using is:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Button AddButton

    public MainPage()
    {
        CreateInterestEntry();
    }

    private void CreateInterestEntry()
    {
        EntrySegment = getEntrySegment();
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(EntrySegment);
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Stuff to do when button is clicked
    }

    private Grid getEntrySegment()
    {
        Grid EntrySegment = new Grid();

       //Creating the grid goes here

        AddButton = new Button();
        AddButton.Content = "Add";
        AddButton.Click += new EventHandler(AddButton_Click);

        return EntrySegment;
    }
}
```

}

With this code it complains that no overload for AddButton_Click matches delegate "System.EventHandler".

It's virtually identical to the code under Examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) at msdn, with the exception I've changed the argument type in AddButton_Click from EventArgs to RoutedEventArgs as otherwise Visual Studio tells me that it cannot implicitly convert from System.EventHandler to System.RoutedEventHandler.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AddButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(AddButton_Click);
```

And the Click Event Handler:

```
void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```